# In a sub, when calling a self-written function that includes a loop, how to avoid the complication of the re-use of function inputs within the loop?

Tags: vba, function, for-loop, subroutine

The calculation for the function is implemented in the loops and at the end the function is set equal to the array achieved by the loop. The function works fine. However when I write a sub to return the array (and define the input as range again) there is an error since previously in the function in the loops the input is used and my guess is that the sub sees it as overwritten.

```
Function discount_factors(swap_rates As Range) As Variant

    Dim swap_matrix(1 To 5, 1 To 5) As Double

For i = 1 To 5
    For j = 1 To 5
        swap_matrix(i, j) = 0
    Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To 5
    For j = 1 To 5 - i
        swap_matrix(i + j, i) = swap_rates(j + i, 1)
    Next j
    swap_matrix(i, i) = 1 + swap_rates(i, 1)
Next i

inverse_matrix = Application.WorksheetFunction.MInverse(swap_matrix)


Dim df(1 To 5, 1 To 1) As Double

For i = 1 To 5
    df(i, 1) = 0
    For j = 1 To 5
        df(i, 1) = df(i, 1) + inverse_matrix(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

discount_factors=df

End Function




Sub result()

Dim swap_rates As Range

inputs = Sheet1.Range("A7:B11").Value

Sheet1.Range("C7:C11")=discount_factors(swap_rates)

End Sub
```

When I run it, it debugs and jumps to the first loop, referring to the fact that the dimensions of swap_rates used in the input has changed I assume. How can I fix this issue so that my sub runs without this complication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and there was just a little thing you've to change if my thoughts are correct:

```
Sub result()

     Dim swap_rates As Range

     Set swap_rates = Sheet1.Range("A7:B11")

     Sheet1.Range("C7:C11") = discount_factors(swap_rates)

End Sub
```

It's working for me, but I don't know if it's what you want. :)